# Некорректная работа ввода с консоли

Tags: c#

```
cki = Console.ReadKey(true);
if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape) break;

var choice = Console.ReadLine();

switch (choice)
{
    case "1":
        Console.WriteLine("1");
        break;
    case "2":
        Console.WriteLine("2");;
        break;
    case "3":
        Console.WriteLine("3");
        break;
}
```

Проблема в том, что при попытки ввести допустим "1", приходится нажимать дважды на клавишу. Я подозреваю,что это из-за подряд идущих Console.ReadKey и Console.ReadLine. Как можно исправить эту проблему?

Comment: ввод может быть только односимвольным?

Comment: да. на попытку иного ввода срабатывает блок default, который информирует о возможных вариантах ввода.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Единственный вариант, который я вижу, — создать свою альтернативу `Console.ReadLine()`, которая будет реагировать не только на Enter, но и на Escape:

```
/// <summary>
/// Console extensions.
/// </summary>
public static class ConsoleEx
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Reads the next line of characters from the standard input stream.
  /// </summary>
  /// <returns>
  /// A line of characters read from the input stream, or <c>null</c> if ESC was pressed.
  /// </returns>
  public static string TryReadLine()
  {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for (;;)
    {
      ConsoleKeyInfo info = Console.ReadKey(true);

      switch (info.Key)
      {
        case ConsoleKey.Enter:
          Console.WriteLine();
          return builder.ToString();

        case ConsoleKey.Escape:
          return null;

        default:
          Console.Write(info.KeyChar);
          builder.Append(info.KeyChar);
          break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Использование в вашем случае будет таким:

```
string choice = ConsoleEx.TryReadLine();

switch (choice)
{
  case "1":
  case "2":
  case "3":
    Console.WriteLine(choice);
    break;
  case null:
    // Handle ESC here.
    break;
  default:
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid input");
    break;
}
```

Comment: здорово) крутая фишка.

Comment: @cruim то есть вам подходит этот вариант?

Comment: да. сохранил себе,наверняка еще пригодится. только не совсем понятно эта строчка for(;;), можно в двух словах? спасибо

Comment: `for(;;)` — это вечный цикл, альтернативный вариант записи `while(true)`.

Answer (score 1):

Вроде бы, работает так:

```
var key = Console.ReadKey(intercept: true);
if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
    break;
var line = "";
if (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)
{
    Console.Write(key.KeyChar);
    line = key.KeyChar + Console.ReadLine();
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: Так сработает только если пользователь нажимает ESC в самом начале строки. После начала ввода символов ESC уже не сработает.

Comment: @ДмитрийШевченко: Ну да, но автору это вроде бы и не нужно, насколько я понимаю? Если нужно, то ваш вариант выглядит правильнее.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Console.ReadKey(true)
> ```

```
Console.In.Peek()
```

Comment: ты уверен что это так же отработает? если не ошибаюсь readkey ждет нажатия, а Peek?

Comment: @Grundy, да pick не ждёт ничего. Надо дополнительно ожидание как-то приделать.

Comment: @Grundy, впрочем, в вопросе всё равно что-то не то. `Esc` во время ввода строки ведь обрабатываться не будет.

Comment: Ага :-) поэтому тут readkey и стоит :):):)

Comment: @Grundy, был уверен, что консоль умеет сама и peek и ungetc, но что-то ничего на эту тему не гуглится хорошего...

Comment: видимо вариант с дополнительным блоком case "q": Environment.Exit(0); break; будет менее раздражительным для пользователя.